# App crashes on pressing back button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

app crashes when pressing back button

log description:-
[FootballScoreBoardViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5aae9e0

Ithink this method is not called but how to sort the problem
Please help
Thanks in ad

Comment: you already release FootballScoreBoardViewController. Can you show your code ?

Comment: I think you are calling a deallocated instance. Can you post some code. Also do make sure that you are not releasing any object before it is used completely

Comment: Post some code here so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might deallocating some released or unallocated item in the dealloc {} part or some items may gets released without allocating the same like array or variable or lable etc.

Or else you might calling the array without the values .

check the same by debugging you'll get answer definetely

Answer (score 1):

This means that you are calling a method on an object that has been released.

You may be calling release 1 too many times on a object. Use zombies to diagnose whats going on. Without posting some code its hard to tell whats going on

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your answer.

Finally I got the solution of my problem. There was one delegate method that was called so simply I set to nil in `dealloc` method.